# Control Shift Click on Mac?

Tags: shaders

The Control+ Shift+ Click key is not working for me at all. I usually do a lot of shading in my blender, but while i was trying to make a 3D Black hole i couldn't do a certain command.Whenever i'm in shading i try to Control+Shift+Click but it does nothing, since i am on MAC, i don't know what control replaces it?I looked at all kinds of fixes for it but i couldn't seem to find what i was looking for. Does anyone have an answer?

Comment: I'm guessing you're using "Ctrl + Shift + Click" so you can preview a node quickly? This is a feature of the Node Wrangler add-on, do you have it enabled?

Comment: Have you turned on the Node Wrangler Addon??